# При открытии файлов для парсинга по очереди не работает цикл

Tags: php

В общем. Есть 3 файла для парсинга. Есть два варианта **подключения** их

```
for ($q=1; $q<4; $q++)  
{  
    $str='page0'.$q.'.html';  
    $string = "";  
    $string=file_ get_contents($str); 
}
```

и

```
$pages = array();  
$pages[] = "page01.html";  
$pages[] = "page02.html";  
$pages[] = "page03.html";  
$string = "";  
foreach ($pages as $key)   
{  
    $string .= file_ get_contents($key);  
}
```

Идеально работает второй, но нужен *первый* вариант. Подскажите, что нужно заменить?
весь код скину по запросу. Прошу помочь ибо сам уже в непонятках...

Comment: Спасибо)
у меня из головы вылетело просто

Answer (score 4):

В первом варианте нет конкатенации (`$string=file_ get_contents`) результатов чтения, а во втором присутствует (`$string .= file_ get_contents`).